# How to loop getprotent() function

Tags: c, sockets

I believe `getprotoent()` function gets values from `/etc/protocols`.

I made the following sample program: test.c.

It shows

> proto.p_name      = ip
>   *proto.p_aliases  = IP
>   proto.p_proto     = 0

These values are the same as the first entry in `/etc/protocols`.

I want to know how I can get the values of the 2nd entries like looping with evaluate some pointers not using `getprotobyname()` or `getprotobynumber()`.

Test.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <netdb.h>

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    protEnt();
}

int protEnt()
{
    setprotoent(2);
    struct protoent proto;
    proto = *getprotoent();
    printf("proto.p_name      = %s\n",proto.p_name);
    printf("*proto.p_aliases  = %s\n",*proto.p_aliases);
    printf("proto.p_proto     = %d\n",proto.p_proto);
    proto = *getprotoent();
    endprotoent();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call `getprotoent()` all over and over again and get next entry on each call.. You just need to check it for `NULL` which means there are no entries left. This means that you need to change your `proto` variable to be pointer.

So something like this:

```
struct protoent *proto;
while((proto = getprotoent()) != NULL)
{
        printf("proto.p_name      = %s\n",(*proto).p_name);
        printf("*proto.p_aliases  = %s\n",*(*proto).p_aliases);
        printf("proto.p_proto     = %d\n",(*proto).p_proto);
}
```