# Loop to get multiple entries in host, network, protocol, and service database

Tags: c, loops, segmentation-fault, hostent

I am having a hard time understanding a previous assignment.  I was to use functions given in the Addison-Wesley *Advanced Programming in the UNIX Environment* Third edition text (chapter 16.3.3) to print the host, network, protocol, and services database to the standard output.  The feedback my professor gave is below.

Needs serious work (-40); each section of the output needs to contain (possibly) many entries, and must be read in a loop Service port numbers incorrect (-5); the port is a short (NOT an int and in network byte order!); it must be converted using ntohs(3).

My issue is in looping the program to get multiple entries, as I'm not sure how this can be done, especially with the addresses in h_addr_list, since I get Segfaults trying to access anything past [0].  Does the loop have anything to do with the value of h_length?

Here is the code as submitted for the feedback above:

```
   /*
    * Dawson Binder
    * Assignment 10 - assign10.c
    * displays the host, network, protocol, and services databases. 
    */
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <netdb.h>
    #include <arpa/inet.h>
    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        char address[36];
        struct hostent *hPtr = gethostent();    // print host name, address type, address length, and the addresses
        struct netent *nPtr = getnetent();
        struct protoent *pPtr = getprotoent();
        struct servent *sPtr = getservent();

        // Host
        printf("\nHost Name: %s\nAddress Type: %d\nAddress Length: %d\n", hPtr->h_name, hPtr->h_addrtype, hPtr->h_length);
        inet_ntop(AF_INET, hPtr->h_addr_list[0], address, 36);
        printf("Address: %s\n", address);
        // end Host

        // Network
        printf("Network Name: %s\nNetwork Number: %u\n", nPtr->n_name, nPtr->n_net);
        // end Network

        //Protocol
        printf("Protocol Name: %s\nProtocol Number: %d\n", pPtr->p_name, pPtr->p_proto);
        //end Protocol

        //Service Database
                printf("Service Database Name: %s\nService Database Port: %d\nServiceDatabase Protocol: %s\n\n", sPtr->s_name, sPtr->s_port, sPtr->s_proto);    
        //end Service Database
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each time you call those four `get*ent()` functions, they will return one entry of their database, until they return `NULL`. Read their manpage to know more, e.g. [`getservent(3)`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getservent). You may also want to close the database connection with their `end*net()` counterparts.

See also related questions like [How to loop getprotent() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20647436/how-to-loop-getprotent-function).